# Problem getting timer to work after cancelling one iteration and starting another

Tags: android, timer, handler

I am stuck trying to get my timer to work, where I will do one countdown, then go back and do another.

So, on the second call to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` I get an `IllegalStateException`, but I am cancelling the `TimerTask` not the `Timer`.

What I want to do is count down twenty seconds, then ten seconds, then repeat, updating a text box each time, to inform the user what they should be doing.

One issue is that the countdown is faster than once/second.

```
04-22 01:34:57.118: DEBUG/TestHandler1(404): message called:2:null
04-22 01:34:57.709: DEBUG/TestHandler1(404): message called:3:null
04-22 01:34:57.899: DEBUG/TestHandler1(404): message called:4:null
04-22 01:34:58.198: DEBUG/TestHandler1(404): message called:5:null
```

Here is my exception:

```
04-22 01:35:48.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
04-22 01:35:48.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(404):     at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:574)
04-22 01:35:48.529: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(404):     at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:530)
```

Here is the code I used for this attempt.  When I tried to use a different timertask for each loop it was even worse behavior, as I put the `new TimerTask` block just before `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`, so I went back to this version.

```
    handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            counterText.setText((new Date()).toString() + "  "
                    + Integer.toString(cntr));
            System.out.println("handleMessage");
        }
    };

    timertask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            cntr++;
            if (cntr > maxReps) {
                timertask.cancel();
                cntr = 0;
            }
        }
    };
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                cntr = 0;
                for (MyClass mclass : input.getLoop()) {
                    labelText.setText(mclass.getName());
                    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                        maxReps = 20;
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);
                        maxReps = 10;
                        labelText.setText("Rest");
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);
                    }
                }
        }
    });
```

Hopefully someone can point out a simple mistake that I made.

Above is a snippet of my code from the `Activity`, so I am including just what I think is needed to show where I am having a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this article in the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html and a similar post here: http://cart.kolix.de/?p=1438 , I would suggest you to change the strategy and use `handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);`

But, specifically to the code, my guess is that it may get cancelled the wrong task. I don't really understand the rationale for having two calls to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timertask, 0, 1000);` and setting `maxReps = 20;` first and then `maxReps = 10;` in the same loop, because the loop will not wait for the task to complete before continuing.

So, you are sending at least 16 calls to `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` and not all may get cancelled at the right time.

Comment: I will try the handler.postDelayed approach again. I tried it and couldn't get it to do what I want.  I am leaning toward just using Thread.sleep(1000) which will force my activity to pause, then I show an update, and continue.

Comment: @James Thread.sleep should work. I think the problem is to have a loop assigning a static/global variable (maxReps) and launching asynchronous tasks to read it. Blocking the for loop while waiting should solve that.

Comment: The thread.sleep didn't work, as it won't get access to the UI components, and seems to mess up how the Activity is working, and the postDelayed also didn't have access to the UI components, so I finally had to get to the handler.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with various methods, I finally settled on this solution.

In my `OnCreate` method I had this code, and it would go 20 seconds then exit.

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String s = msg.getData().getString("counter");
            counterText.setText(s);
            Log.d("Activity.handleMessage", s);
        }
    };

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

            while (true) {
                Message m = new Message();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("counter", Integer.toString(cntr));
                m.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessageDelayed(m, cntr * 1000);
                if (cntr++ == maxReps) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exerciseText.setText(model.getName());
            counterText.setText("0");
            maxReps = 20;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    });
```

Part of my difficulty is not thinking about how Android works.  I found various approaches that didn't work well.