# Subtract the time in countdown timer android

Tags: android, timer

can someone help me on how to minus or subtract the time in my countdown timer? for example the countdown timer is running and when i click a button it will be diminished by 3, but it will still running. please help me, thank a lot in advance.

here is what i have ...

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
 }.start();
```

Comment: There is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843832/can-the-time-on-a-countdowntimer-be-updated